# Collage of Words With CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Goal:** I want to create a collage of words with little spacing in order to semi-display the background image. Something similar to [this](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/f6/c5/5e/f6c55e9bc90d2ac7a3856f730f7eccfe.jpg) but with words.

**Problem:** Whenever I add an image to the background of the text, it messes with the format of the text

```css
.body-container{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #fff;
}
.body-container h1{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;

 left:0;
 top:0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

 display: inline-block;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 34px;
    height: 35px;

    
  background: url(path/to/image) no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<div class='container body-container'>
  <h1>Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite </h1>

 </div>
```

Comment: " it messes with the format of the text" - What do you mean?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/41GUL  the first one is with the image added and the second one is without.

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve, can you edit your code and put the image so we can visualize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you gave the h1 a height of 35px. Remove that and it works with adding `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;`. I believe you also don't need the `height:100%` that's on the h1.

```css
.body-container{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #fff;
}
.body-container h1{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
  height:100%;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 width: 100%;

 display: inline-block;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 34px;

    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background: url(http://fillmurray.com/460/300) no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<div class='container body-container'>
  <h1>Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite Inspite </h1>

 </div>
```

Comment: Nice job.. Thanks